# How to set image for NavigationBar title using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar, titleview

I want to set an image in the titleView of NavigationBar using SwiftUI.
We can do this by using UIKit as below:

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
```

This is how we do it in UIKit.

How can I use SwiftUI to achieve this?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546213/how-to-put-a-logo-in-navigationview-in-swiftui?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I actually moved my answer to this other thread. If it works for you, feel free to accept the pending duplicate vote.

Comment: Does that answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62450368/12299030?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **SwiftUI 2** you can create a `ToolbarItem` with the `principal` placement:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Test")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```